# react 18.2 does not automatic batch state updates

Tags: reactjs

I am using react 18.2 and I have 3 setStates that won't batch, what is the problem? I have a flushSync before fetching of data, could it have any effect on the batching? the fetchMenuById method is also called inside of an useEffect

```
  const fetchMenuById = useCallback(
    (pageId: number) => {
      !loading &&
        flushSync(() => {
          setLoading(true);
        }); // trigger rerender
      if (drawerContentList[pageId]) {
        //if already fetched before
        setDrawerContent(drawerContentList[pageId]);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        //else get new
        NavigationApi.getMenuFragment(pageId)
          .then((data) => {
            const newMenu: { [key: string]: MenuType } = {};
            newMenu[pageId] = data;
            console.log('setcontentlist');
            setDrawerContentList({ ...drawerContentList, ...newMenu });
            console.log('setcontent');
            setDrawerContent(data);
            console.log('setloadingfalse');
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            setDrawerContent(null);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      }
    },
    [drawerContentList, loading],
  );
```

I am using a functional react component and have a console.log('render) just before my return in the component. Unfortunately the console.log prints for each of the state updates:

```
setcontentlist
render
setcontent
render
setloadingfalse
render
```

Comment: Do you use react-router too?

Comment: not inside this component no, but other compents yes. (is also not wrapped inside any reac-router components)

Comment: Try to set state outside of the getMenuFragment to test if it works.

Comment: already tried to setLoading(true) alternating between true and false 5 times, but it still printed out "render" every update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my underlying issue, was using reactjs/React.NET to serve my components, and its version was still 17.0.2. Upgraded and it now works

Answer (score 0):

In order to batch state updates, they need to be executed in the same synchronous context. Wrap your state updates like this using react-dom :

```
import { batch } from 'react-dom';

...

NavigationApi.getMenuFragment(pageId)
  .then((data) => {
    const newMenu: { [key: string]: MenuType } = {};
    newMenu[pageId] = data;
    batch(() => {
      console.log('setcontentlist');
      setDrawerContentList({ ...drawerContentList, ...newMenu });
      console.log('setcontent');
      setDrawerContent(data);
      console.log('setloadingfalse');
      setLoading(false);
    });
  })
```

Comment: there is no batch from react-dom? and doesn't batching happen automatically with react 18?

Comment: You are right ! Sorry I didn't take in consideration the fact that youre using the 18.2 version...

Comment: In React 18 with createRoot, all updates are automatically batched, no matter where they originate from.